# Gawk regexp to select sequence

Tags: regex, gawk

sorry for the nth simple question on regexp but I'm not able to get what I need without a what seems to me a too complicated solution. I'm parsing a file containing sequence of only 3 letters A,E,D as in

`AADDEEDDA`

`EEEEEEEE`

`AEEEDEEA`

`AEEEDDAAA`

and I'd like to identify only those that start with E and ends in D with only one change in the sequence as for example in

`EDDDDDDDD`

`EEEDDDDDD`

`EEEEEEEED`

I'm fighting with the proper regexp to do that. Here my last attempt

`echo "1,AAEDDEED,1\n2,EEEEDDDD,2\n3,EDEDEDED" | gawk -F, '{if($2 ~ /^E[(ED){1,1}]*D$/ && $2 !~ /^E[(ED){2,}]*D$/) print $0}'`

which does not work. Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your attempts. Doing that helps because it allows people who answer to explain where you went wrong and explain how their answers differ from your attempts (what the material confusion/etc. was).

Comment: Think anchors and character class. What have you tried?

Comment: edit your question to include your attempts to solve your problem. Don't extend a conversation in comments about basic details of your problem. OK? :-) Good luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "with only one change in the sequence"?

Comment: Missed an opportunity to title your post "Gawk at my ED".

Answer (score 5):

If i understand correctly your request a simple

```
awk '/^E+D+$/' file.input
```

will do the trick.

**UPDATE**: if the line format contains pre/post numbers (with post optional) as showed later in the example, this can be a possible pure regex adaptation (alternative to the use of field switch`-F,`):

```
awk '/^[0-9]+,E+D+(,[0-9]+)?$/' input.test
```

Comment: How about `$2 ~ /^E+[^ED]*D+$/`?

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly and I definitely need to find some time to study regexp.

Comment: @G.Tartifola check out [RexEgg](http://www.rexegg.com) for some tutorials. Also see my answer below for a more detailed explanation of why the correct AWK program is a lot simpler than the one you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need the regular expression:

```
^E+[^ED]*D+$
```

This matches one or more `E`s at the beginning, zero or more characters that are neither `E` nor `D` in the middle, and one or more `D`s at the end.

Then your AWK program will look like

```
$2 ~ /^E+[^ED]*D+$/
```

`$2` refers to the 2nd field of the current record, `~` is the regex matching operator, and `/`s delimit a regular expression. Together, these components form what is known in AWK jargon as a "pattern", which amounts to a boolean filter for input records. Note that there is no "action" (a series of statements in `{`s) specified here. That's because when no action is specified, AWK assumes that the action should be `{ print $0 }`, which prints the entire line.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: This solution does not work as expected, the ``[^ED]`` section of the regex will match unwanted string such as EEEAADDDD ([^ED]* will match 'AA'). View this example [online](https://regex101.com/r/xQ9vA4/1)

Comment: I see. Thanks for the link, the page seems very useful.

Comment: @GsusRecovery maybe I misread the OP, but I thought that's what they wanted

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct you want to match patterns that starts with at least one E and then continues with at least one D until the end.

```
echo "1,AAEDDEED,1\n2,EEEEDDDD,2\n3,EDEDEDED" | gawk -F, '{if($2 ~ /^E+D+$) print $0}'
```